# Convert querySelector() value to boolean

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to read the value of a HTML meta tag:

```
<meta name="accepted-cookies" content="false" />
```

From a react component (using Typescript) I want to read the value as a boolean:

```
const metaValue = (document.querySelector('meta[name="accepted-cookies"]')).value === "true";
```

But I'm getting the error `TS2339: (JS) Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Element'.`

Comment: That's an attribute of the element, not `value`.

Comment: See [Element#getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

Comment: "content" != "value". Furthermore, `querySelector()` returns an `Element`, so you can only access properties that exist on that interface. If you want to access properties specific to the sub-type (in this case `HTMLMetaElement`), you would need to cast it to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getAttribute` to avoid having to cast (assert) the result to `HTMLMetaElement`:

```
const metaValue = document.querySelector('meta[name="accepted-cookies"]')!.getAttribute("content") === "true";
//                                                                       ^? non-null assertion
```